# After upgrading my app to null safety, red line under docs

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

In my complete project, I'm getting red line under docs whereever I have used it after upgrading to null safety.

```
FutureBuilder(
                  future: db
                      .collection('orders')
                      .where('status', isEqualTo: 'pending')
                  .where('items',arrayContains: this.widget.nameShop)
                      .get(),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (!snapshot.hasData)
                      return Center(
                        child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                          backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                        ),
                      );
                int count = snapshot.data!.docs.length; //Here on this line
                    return new ListView.builder(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                      itemCount: count,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
                          inventoryTile(
                              context, snapshot.data!.docs[index], index),
                    );
                  }),
```

Compiler gives error that:

```
error: The getter 'docs' isn't defined for the type 'Object'.
```

Might be something is deprecated. Help please!
I will provide any further information if required.

Comment: Is Er1's answer the solution to your issue or do you still need help? (it would seem they're right, but I'd rather ask and be sure)

Comment: Er1's helped. He is right. I need to give the type of object with future builder in order to build something inside build function.

Comment: For visibility reasons, may I ask that you accept their answer? (That way this question shows up as having an accepted answer)

Comment: Yeah fabc. I have accepted their answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define what kind of object `snapshot.data` is so you can call the defined methods.
You can do that by setting the type argument for the FutureBuilder
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html

For example if the future returns a DocumentSnapshots:

```dart
FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>()
```